# Push the last data grid row to the bottom of the grid

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm trying to make a summary footer for the datagrid that will display a totals or summation of all the values in all rows of specific columns. Unfortunately, it's not supported in Clarity datagrid. There is a workaround as mentioned in the comments in this github issue: [#2809](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2809). However, my goal is to have the summary row/footer sit/anchored to the bottom of the grid. Is there a way to do it via css to push the last row to the bottom of the grid?

Actual: [From the Stackblitz provided in the github issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-total?file=src/app/app.component.html)

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [imgbbb.com](https://imgbbb.com/images/2019/02/08/grid-2.png))</sub>

Expected:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [imgbbb.com](https://imgbbb.com/images/2019/02/08/grid.png))</sub>

Comment: Do you really need a datagrid for this? A normal table would probably be better.

Comment: @JeremyWilken I do need a datagrid for that. It has a lot of features that a normal table can't provide. The app that I'm making contains a lot of financial data so totals & summations are necessary. It's a common design for enterprise apps that use data grids. It would be better if I can push it all the way to the bottom and pin it there. Too bad I can't do it with the datagrid for now. I guess I need to make alternative design solutions.

Comment: The Datagrid doesn't have this feature, and you could go about overloading the ClrDatagridFooter to have it show this row and you'd be in charge of adding it (instead of trying to modify the behavior of the last row), which would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

With Css You can do the following

```
#total {
  border-top-style: dashed;
  margin-top: 50%;
 }
```